# Selenium IDE how to select an object by DIV

Tags: selenium-webdriver, selenium-ide

I have the following element on a page (it's a button with the word Next that you click)

```
<div class="aaabutton">
                    <div class="aaacontainer">
                        <div class="aaatext">
                            Next
                        </div>
                   </div>
</div>
```

No matter what I try it can't find it.
Tried following:

```
css=.show .aaacontainer 

xpath=//div[@id='Next']/div[3]/div[2]/div/div

xpath=//div[3]/div[9]/div[3]/div[2]/div/div
```

Times out trying to find it (for example Trying to find xpath=//div[@id='Next']/div[3]/div[2]/div/div... Failed:)

Comment: can you share all your Selenium code including the link to that page?

Answer (score 0):

Since you didn't share all your existing code trials and a link to that page we can only guess. So, I guess this may work:

```
xpath="//div[@id='Next']//div[@class='aaabutton'][contains(.,'Next')]"
```

Comment: Thanks.  It didn't work.  its is behind firewall.  This is the code for element.                                                                                                                               <div id="Next" class="cpButton Next" role="button" aria-label="Next" onclick="processAction(this.id);" >
       <div class="default">
          <div class="btnimg normal show"> 
           <div class="aaabutton">
           <div class="aaacontainer">
           <div class="aaatext">
        Next
                         </div>
     </div>
  </div>
 </div>
     </div>
    </div>

Comment: It's not readable. Please put this inside the question. Also, please share all your selenium code.